# How to Logout facebook button completely include (change text 'log out' to 'log in with facebook' ) from another activity

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to logout fb button from another activity but problem is when i logout from another activity.Facebook button show with logout text and not logout completely it means again click on logout then logout the fb button.

Comment: See link what i want

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6grZ1diXtmHM3AwYzlpWGZPc3M

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6grZ1diXtmHeVZGb0x3cFZSRFE

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6grZ1diXtmHM2NweHA0cnJNLTA

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6grZ1diXtmHaWx5a3lkUFN6X3c

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() == null) {
            return; // already logged out
        }else {
            new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), "/me/permissions/", null, HttpMethod.DELETE, new GraphRequest
                    .Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse graphResponse) {

                    LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();

                }
            }).executeAsync();
        }
```

Comment: Not work for me ! I try this but i want logout in login activity from another activity

Comment: in AnotherActivity, when user clicks logout, start a Intent back to your LoginActivity with a Extra value "logout", in your LoginActivity get the String "logout" and have a if(string == "logout"){ //paste the above code here }

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(LogOutActivity.this);
LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
```

**Note**

1. Uninstall the App
2. Add above code
3. Run

Comment: button change behavior on click event of Facebook Button type